# how to replace div with a string in javascript hangman

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
const secret_word = "emir";

function getTheWord() {
  //var secret_word = document.getElementById("secret").value;

  for (i = 1; i <= secret_word.length; i++) {

    var sw = '<div id="0"</div>';
    sw = '<div id="' + i + '" style="display:inline-block;"> ___ </div>';
    console.log(sw);
  }
  document.getElementById('secret').innerHTML = sw;
}

function getLetter() {
  // var e = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'E';
  // var m = document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 'M';
  // var i = document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'I';
  // var r = document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = 'R';
  // console.log(e);
  // console.log(m);
  var s = document.getElementById("secret1").value;
  console.log(s);
  console.log(value);
}

function GetValue() {
  var my_array = new Array("head", "hand1", "hand2", "body", "leg1", "leg2");
  var random_array = my_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * my_array.length)];
  console.log(random_array);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random_array;
}

getTheWord()
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message"></p>

<div id="secret"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="secret1" maxlength="1" />
<button id="secret" onclick="getLetter();">Enter a Letter</button>
```

I need to replace the div with the const secret_word = emir,  and when i put different letter to invoke the hangman getValue function. Since i am beginner I hope you can help me find a way to do it.or if you have some different resources for me to look i would really appreciate. DOM is like another planet for me right now but if i don't learn whats the point of learning javascript. So help , solution , resources , opinions , advises , even mistakes to tell me i would be very grateful

Comment: I doubt this is super important to you, but do note that if your secret word is available in any way in your front end code, it is not secret to anyone who knows how to use the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery. Have you used it before? 
Try this:

var newDIV = $("  ");

$("#secret").append(newDiv);

I hope I understood the question right?

Comment: Ragland i need to do it in plain javascript